# I wanted to take input from GUI window and store

Tags: java, swing, jframe

here is my GUI

1. during start window will open and take iput HOST, PORT and duration.
2. clicking Connect button it will close the window.

```
public class Frame1 {
    
    public String userText;
    public String pwdText;
    public JFrame frame;
    public JTextField textField;
    public JTextField textField_1;
    public JTextField textField_2;
    public JLabel lblNewLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( new Color(240, 240, 240));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Connect");
        btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //messape
                
                userText = textField.getText();
                pwdText = textField_1.getText();
                System.out.println(userText);
                         
                if(e.getSource()==btnNewButton) {
                       frame.dispose();
                       
                       // This exit Your GUI 
                    }
                

            }
        });
```

And, here is my main program where im calling the **Frame1** in **Connection2**.

here while retreiving values from textfields, its showing null

```
public class Connection2{

    //  public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    //  public static final String PORT = "5555";

    public static String HOST;
    public static String PORT;
    public static long START;
    public static long END;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {


        Frame1 frame = new Frame1();
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("JMX CONNECTION:");
        System.out.println("HOST AND PORT");
        frame.main(args);
        
        
        HOST =frame.userText;
        PORT =frame.pwdText;
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(HOST);
        System.out.println(PORT);
        
        
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        System.out.println(HOST);
        System.out.println("TEST DURATION IN SECONDS");
        System.out.println("DURATON(sec): ");
        int Duration = sc.nextInt();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
JMX CONNECTION

HOST AND PORT
localhost
null
null
```

This output im getting, after giving pause time to thread.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a modal `JDialog`, so you prompt the user for input and when the window is closed, retrieve the values entered

Comment: Maybe start with [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: In addition to the advice of @MadProgrammer, see [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) The accepted answer which presumably still has the code using two frames, is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code it dosn't wait until the user press the button so I gives back a null value.

So a possible way to repair this is adding a method in the connection class that is called when the button is pressed